# Librosa Split .wav file into 15s intervals

Tags: python, librosa

I'm new to working with audio files. I have several 60 second long files that I want to split into 15 second files (or any length). I'm able to split files into 1 second long files (so 60 files) but can't seem to get 15 second intervals to work. How can I create the intervals I'm looking for?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display

audio_dir = r'data\acoustics\recordings'

out_dir = r'data\acoustics\splits'
os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)

audio_file = os.path.join(audio_dir, 'rec_20220729T160547Z.wav')

wave, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=None)  

num_sections = int(np.ceil(len(wave) / sr)

split = []

for i in range(num_sections):
    t = wave[i * sr : i * sr + sr]
    split.append(t)

for i in range(num_sections):
    recording_name = os.path.basename(audio_file[:-4])
    out_file = f"{recording_name}_{str(i)}.wav"
    sf.write(os.path.join(out_dir, out_file), split[i], sr)
```

Comment: Seems like what you want is to use `15 * sr` instead of `sr`.

Comment: where specifically? I change it in `num_sections` and it makes 4 files that are 1 second long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is mostly correct. It just need minor changes.
First is getting the data which you have done correctly.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display
import soundfile as sf  # Missing import

audio_dir = r'data\acoustics\recordings'

out_dir = r'data\acoustics\splits'
os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)

audio_file = os.path.join(audio_dir, 'rec_20220729T160547Z.wav')

wave, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=None)
```

Calculate the length of segment:

```
segment_dur_secs = 15  
segment_length = sr * segment_dur_secs
```

Breaking up the data and saving to file:

```
num_sections = int(np.ceil(len(wave) / segment_length))

split = []

for i in range(num_sections):
    t = wave[i * segment_length: (i + 1) * segment_length]
    split.append(t)

for i in range(num_sections):
    recording_name = os.path.basename(audio_file[:-4])
    out_file = f"{recording_name}_{str(i)}.wav"
    sf.write(os.path.join(out_dir, out_file), split[i], sr)
```

Alternatively:

```
split = []    
for s in range(0, len(wave), segment_length):
    t = wave[s: s + segment_length]
    split.append(t)


recording_name = os.path.basename(audio_file[:-4])
for i, segment in enumerate(split):
    out_file = f"{recording_name}_{i}.wav"
    sf.write(os.path.join(out_dir, out_file), segment, sr)
```

Edit: There is an issue with the code here because `sf` is not defined. (Fixed the import)